# "Failed to open X display" when trying to run project from within Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, opengl, x11, glfw

I have a simple OpenGL/GLFW test program in Eclipse

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_GLU
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>


void errorCallback(int error, const char *description)
{
    std::cerr << description << " (GLFW error " << error << ")" << std::endl;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    int returnValue = 0;
    try {

        // Initialise GLFW.
        glfwSetErrorCallback(errorCallback);
        if(!glfwInit()) throw std::string("Could not initialise GLFW");

        /* ...do everything else... */

    } catch(std::string const &str) {

        std::cerr << "Error: " << str << std::endl;
        returnValue = 1;

    }
    return returnValue
}
```

However, running it causes the following to come up in the console:

```
X11: Failed to open X display (GLFW error 65542)
Error: Could not initialise GLFW
```

i.e. it fails during `glfwInit()` (I commented out all the code just to make sure it doesn't actually happen during window creation or something). However, navigating to the build directory (using my file manager, not Eclipse, that is) and manually launching from there works just fine.

Anyone know what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse indeed wasn't passing any environment variables to my program (thanks datenwolf for getting me started). It's possible to select which environment variables to pass to the program by going to Run Configurations, selecting the appropriate launch configuration under "C/C++ Application" (I only had the default one), opening the Environment tab and then hitting the select button (it lists all available environment variables) and picking which ones you want.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like Eclipse clears all or some of the environment variables when launching the program. The environment variable `DISPLAY` tell the program how to connect to the X11 server. Without that information it can't open the display, giving you that error.

Simple test to verify this: Add the following like right before `glfwInit()` (never mind that this is not C++ and doesn't use iostream, but that's okay for a quick test:

```
fprintf(stderr, "DISPLAY=%s\n", getenv("DISPLAY"));
```

You must include the headers `stdio.h` and `stdlib.h`.

Comment: I got `DISPLAY=(null)`, so I assume this indeed is the problem? Any way to fix this?

Comment: Well, you must make Eclipse pass through the value of the DISPLAY variable. I'm not an Eclipse user myself (I tried a few times to familiarize with it, but it's far too heavyweight for my liking), so I can't help you there. I'd guess you could find it somewhere in the target debugging options, or something like that.

Comment: Yea, I figured how to do that and outlined the steps in my answer